# Sharpie binding objective-c @protocols issue

Tags: xamarin, objective-sharpie

I'm using `sharpie` `bind` command to get API interfaces for my `iOS` library for `xamarin`

```
sharpie bind --namespace=XXX --sdk=iphoneos9.2 Headers/*.h
```

Have issues with `@protocol` bindings:

```
The type or namespace name `IProfileDelegate' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

This is how it's generated:

```
    interface XLibrary : IProfileDelegate
    {
    [Wrap ("WeakProfileDelegate")]
    [NullAllowed]
    MB_ProfileDelegate ProfileDelegate { get; set; }
```

I understand that it creates empty `ProfileDelegate` then compiler or something fills it with methods BUT my issue is that `IProfileDelegate` not found.

```
@protocol ProfileDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)GetProfileFinished:(NSString*)_data;
- (void)SetProfileFinished:(NSString*)_data;
@end
```

Difference here in `I` symbol (which is reserved for @protocols I guess).
How to make `sharpie` generate proper api definitions?

I'm able to remove all `I` prefixes and it compiles successfully but I'd rather fix it not to repeat this every time I need to update source library.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that all the obj-c protocol act as a interface or abstract class i recommend to put "protocol, model and set base type as nsobject, another thing all the methods or properties maked as a "required" you need to specify it as Abstract

```
[Protocol, Model]
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
interface myAwesomeDelegate
{
  [Abstract]
  [Export(...)]
  void myRequiredMethod(uint param1)

  [Export(...)]
  void anotherMethod()
}
```

hope this will help you to fix your issue

Comment: Why do we need to set base type?

Comment: @awattar because his ProfileDelegate obj-c class has NSObject as base class (at)protocol ProfileDelegate <NSObject>

Comment: But when protocol does not use NSObject? http://stackoverflow.com/q/43126822/1142979

Comment: Setting BaseType fixed it for me.

Answer (score -3):

According to the [Objective Sharpie documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform-features/apidefinitions-structsandenums/):

> In some cases these generated files might be all you need, however more often the developer will need to manually modify these generated files to fix any issues that could not be automatically handled by the tool (such as those flagged with a [Verify attribute](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform-features/verify/)).

This means you will sometimes have to adjust the two generated files, ApiDefinitions.cs and StructsAndEnums.cs to fix issues, such as the one in this case.

You can read more about how bindings work for Objective-C protocols, which are similar to C# Interfaces, but not quite [in the binding documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/binding-types-reference/#Protocols).

Comment: [verify ...] directives is clear but my question was about this prefix I